# Will creating a hook that doesn't access to React lifecycle cause problems farther a project grows?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, react-hooks, lifecycle, reusability

I've created a hook called `useFilestack` that now abstracts the logic to upload a file from a binary, but in the future it can grow as needed. So it looks like this:

```
const useFilestack = () => {
  const upload = (binary: string) => {
    const file = Buffer.from(binary, 'binary').toString('base64');

    const filestack = client.init(apiKey);

    filestack.upload(file);
  };

  return {
    upload,
  };
};
```

As you can see, it doesn't access to the React lifecycle using for example some `useEffect` or `useState`.

Is that a bad practice? I'm gonna use this in some many place so it makes sense for me to abstract it in some place.

**EDIT**: I edited the question so it is not opinion-based. Thanks @Heret Monkey for the suggestion.

Comment: It's just currently not a hook so you don't have to use the `use*` naming convention. One could even argue that you shouldn't use it as other people might think this function has to be used like a hook ("Rules of hooks"). A custom hook is not just a function that gets called in a component but a function that actually uses one or more hooks internally. There is nothing bad about it except of maybe the name. Unless you think it will use hooks in the future you can just name it e.g. `uploadBinary` or something that actually describes what it does.

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question. Good/bad practices are opinions of people who can convince other people that their opinions matter. If you really want to know if your code is going to cause problems farther along the road, ask that question.

Comment: @trixn Thanks a lot, that makes sense.

Comment: @trixn Can you write it as an answer so I can select it as the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just currently not a hook so you don't have to use the `use*` naming convention.

One could even argue that you shouldn't use the hooks naming convention as other people might think this function has to be used like a hook ("Rules of hooks").

A custom hook is not just a function that gets called in a component but a function that actually uses one or more hooks internally. There is nothing bad about it except of maybe the name. It's simply a helper function that encapsulates a certain work flow.

Unless you think it will use hooks in the near future you can just name it differently so that other do not confuse it with a hook.